# Can't disable bounce with UIScrollView and pagingEnabled=YES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have `UIViewController` that hold `UIScrollView` inside it.

The `m_scrollView` is with `pagingEnabled=YES;`

On each "page" I have UIViewController that display article.

To prevent bouncing when the user swipe from page to page i used :

`m_scrollView.bounces=NO;`

and even

`m_scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizonal=NO;`

I notice the change was only to the last page that is not bounce.
But when swiping the other pages, they bounce.

**EDIT:**
the optimal solution was make the first and last page bounce ( so the user will get repsond there is no more pages\paging) and the other pages without bouncing

the annoying with the bounce when swiping pages is the bounce effect is not equal and same.
somtimes it bounce more, and somtimes less.

I tought is somthing to do with the loading data in the pages, but I dont think it's the case, cause it happens also when all pages are loaded and no async operation of loading are happening in the background.
Any ideas ?

**EDIT 2 :** 
I guess the bounce property is about the edge of the UIScrollView, 
But when moving from page to page there is also bouncing.
Sometimes I can see a little of next-next page.
For example :
swiping from page 2 to page 3 , and in the animation of swiping I can see for 0.1 second page 4.

Also, the animation of swiping is not constant. and it feel that each swipe acts little diffrent.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "bouncing between pages"? The whole point of bouncing is to "bounce" when user reaches any edge of the scrollview, there is no bouncing between pages in pagingEnabled scroll view.

Comment: If i have 10 "pages" in the scrollview..
When I swipe from page 2 to page 3( for example)
I get randomly this results :
-page 3 reach is border with little "bounce" (going back and forth)
-page 3 reach is border, and i can see little of page 4 before bounce back
-page 3 reach is border and stop(and that's what i want)

again, the animation of swiping is not constant, and it's not UI Friendly.

Hope I'm clear here.

Comment: the behavior depends on how much you drag before releasing, check the scroll delegate methods to see if you can control it with more detail

Comment: hi perr200. i have exactly the same problem,did you find any solution to this please let me know.

Comment: Hey there, do u use `XLPagerTabStrip` framework? I had this prob but available to solve simply.

Answer (score 19):

just do this:

```
_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
_scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
_scrollView.bounces = NO; //Here
```

then, no bounce any more!

Answer (score 2):

Bouncing refers only to the edges of the content. Not the the small movement when swiping from page to page.

This movement is caused by the paging effect.

It also happens when setting the scrollView.isPagingEnable to true when the page is already on the page.

To prevent this movement, I had to set the paging to false before
calling:

```
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false

collectionView.setContentOffset(requiredOffset, animated: true)
```

and set the paging back to true in:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: I want you to know out of the thousands of posts I've read about this issue, this is the hack that solved this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you set a delegate for your UIScrollView, the delegate will receive `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:` when the user lifts their finger off the screen. You *may* then be able to take control using the UIScrollView's `setContentOffset:animated:` method to scroll the nearest page into view, or set up your own animation using the `animateWithDuration:animations:` method – I'm not sure whether your own animation will take precedence over the already-in-progress deceleration, though.

You can also set the UIScrollView's `decelerationRate` to `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast`, which may make the scrolling more consistent in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

set scrollbar's bounce property false/no....it will not bounce after that... try it hope yu will get your solution....