# Disable vertical bounce effect in an ipad web app

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, cordova, mobile-safari

Is there a way to disable the bounce effect in a scrolling div?

So far I have tried these things but none worked. Please help!

[How to disable vertical bounce/scroll on iPhone in a mobile web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669670/how-to-disable-vertical-bounce-scroll-on-iphone-in-a-mobile-web-application)

[Can't disable bounce with UIScrollView and pagingEnabled=YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003261/cant-disable-bounce-with-uiscrollview-and-pagingenabled-yes)

[ipad safari: disable scrolling, and bounce effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768269/ipad-safari-disable-scrolling-and-bounce-effect)

[Disable UITableView vertical bounces when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768673/disable-uitableview-vertical-bounces-when-scrolling)

And

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/996-turn-off-scrolling-bounces-uiwebview.html

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Error Console for any of the solutions?

Comment: Ok. Some of your links mention UIScrollView or UITableView, so those won't help you if you are making an HTML page. Can you post your implementation of one of the JavaScript techniques you used?

Comment: This is one of the approaches that I have used -      document.ontouchmove = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}                                                                   var myDiv =document.getElementById("scrollableDiv");  myDiv.ontouchmove = function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); }

Comment: I have wrapped this web app in XCode using PhoneGap. Also tried myScrollView.bounces=NO;                                             And                                                    [(UIScrollView*)[webview.subviews objectAtIndex:0]  setAllowsRubberBanding:NO];                                          Here I need the div to scroll but not bounce. Not sure if it's possible.

Comment: The link I posted also looks like it also has a PhoneGap solution. You may want to try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this may not be the best way but it works.

Here is what I did -

```
#scrollableDiv {
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}

document.getElementById("scrollableDiv").innerHTML = longText;
document.getElementById("scrollableDiv").scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: To avoid horizontal bouncing, make sure the content does not overflow.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Cordova 1.7, just open the **Cordova.plist** file and set the key **UIWebViewBounce** to **NO**.

Comment: Fortunately this guy found a better solution, Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Open your phoneGap project's `config.xml` file and change UIWebViewBounce from default true to false:

```
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

Can't imagine why the default is true...

Comment: I believe the new preference if you have a later version of phonegap/cordova is <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />     At least that's what worked for me with cordova 2.7.0

Comment: The last comment of russter works perfect for me in cordova 3.3 My life was saved. thx.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, the code your are using is the disable scrolling altogether. If you want scrolling, but without the bounce effect, try something like this:

```
var xStart, yStart = 0;

document.getElementById("scrollableDiv").addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
    xStart = e.touches[0].screenX;
    yStart = e.touches[0].screenY;
});

document.getElementById("scrollableDiv").addEventListener('touchmove',function(e) {
    var xMovement = Math.abs(e.touches[0].screenX - xStart);
    var yMovement = Math.abs(e.touches[0].screenY - yStart);
    if((yMovement * 3) > xMovement) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I found this solution [here](http://gregsramblings.com/2012/05/23/preventing-vertical-scrolling-bounce-using-javascript-on-ios-devices/). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks but this disables bouncing as well as scrolling.

Comment: I just edited the code. I should have used `document.getElementById("scrollableDiv").addEventListener(...` instead of `document.addEventListener(...` in both places. That might be why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you out place the .scroll class on the element you wish to still have scrolling.

Whats happening is all touch moves are disabled by default. If the element you wish to scroll has the .scroll class on it then it sets the gate to true to allow it to pass.

On touch end you reset the gate to false.

This works on IOS5 and 6 and could work in Chrome and Safari 

Look @ this post to extend it
 [How to prevent page scrolling when scrolling a DIV element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600454/how-to-prevent-page-scrolling-when-scrolling-a-div-element)

The only catch to this is that if you over scroll the scrollable element the elastic effect allows the scroll to be passed up the tree while scroll is set to true. Manually setting the scroll position gets overridden by the dreaded bounce effect.
I bet those Apple friggers have a native implementation of scroll running in a set time out with each step hard wired in.
 
 So if you scroll to -20, I think it hard wires each step into a loop not checking where it was. Scrolling to -20 -19 -18 etc in sequence.
 We must think of a way around this! ( in fact typing it out load I have an idea! )

```
$(function(){
  var scroll = false
  var scroll_element;
  $('body').on('touchmove',function(e){
      if(!scroll){
      e.preventDefault()
      }
  })
  $('body').on('touchend',function(e){
      scroll = false
  })  
  $('.scroll').on('touchstart',function(e){
      scroll_element = this
      scroll = true
  })  
})
```