# iPad bottom:0px issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, jquery-mobile

I am making a [testing webapp using jQuery mobile](http://derek1906.site50.net/experiment/webapp/test/app.html) on iPad, and something just don't go as what I expected.

```
.ui-footer-fixed {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This should makes the `footer` to stay at the bottom at all time, but Safari decided to not to agree with it. When you get to the bottom of the page, then you can pull up the whole webpage, which is what I don't want. Is it possible to fix it or is it a limitation of a webapp?

[image: up]
[image]

Also, other than that, is it possible to make the header `top: 0px` without making the whole page going up? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the header or the footer, you should use the attribute `data-position="fixed"`.

Check the online doc for more information: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

I think the problem you're encountering is linked to the integrated webview of the iPad. This "webview bounce" cannot be avoided if you're developing a simple webapp.

However, you may have a look at these workaround: [Disable vertical bounce effect in an ipad web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761746/disable-vertical-bounce-effect-in-an-ipad-web-app)

Comment: Thanks. For the "disable vertical bounce" problem, is it possible to use `<body>` as the fixed container?

Comment: OK, I tried everything and also googled for a while, none of the solutions work. So I guess it is not possible to get rid of the bounce effect?