# disable bounce / rubber band effect on DIVs in Phonegap

Tags: css, cordova, horizontal-scrolling

I am creating a Phonegap app and have a div with a fixed height that I would like to scroll horizontally on touch. To do this I've added a:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
```

CSS rule.  It works great, but I would like to disable the bounce effect effect when I reach the top and bottom of this div.  The bounce effect is causing some unpleasant user experiences in the app.

I do have the Phonegap option

```
UIWebViewBounce
```

Set to NO, but that doesn't seem to affect this div.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: UIWebViewBounce is just for the entire page I believe, I've set that to NO to remove the nasty effect of being able to drag up/down on e.g. A navigation bar and get the bounce. This may help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761746/disable-vertical-bounce-effect-in-an-ipad-web-app

Answer (score 1):

Just modify following preference in your `config.xml`:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```