# Disable vertical bounce but not scrolling in a div

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, cordova, mobile-safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable vertical bounce effect in an ipad web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761746/disable-vertical-bounce-effect-in-an-ipad-web-app)

Is there a way to disable the bounce effect in a scrolling div?

So far I have tried these things but none have worked. Please help!

- [How to disable vertical bounce/scroll on iPhone in a mobile web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669670/how-to-disable-vertical-bounce-scroll-on-iphone-in-a-mobile-web-application)
- [Can't disable bounce with UIScrollView and pagingEnabled=YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003261/cant-disable-bounce-with-uiscrollview-and-pagingenabled-yes)
- [ipad safari: disable scrolling, and bounce effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768269/ipad-safari-disable-scrolling-and-bounce-effect)
- [Disable UITableView vertical bounces when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768673/disable-uitableview-vertical-bounces-when-scrolling)

And

- http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/996-turn-off-scrolling-bounces-uiwebview.html

Thanks!

Comment: You asked the same question few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761746/disable-vertical-bounce-effect-in-an-ipad-web-app/10801645 This is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (id subview in webView.subviews)
  if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
  ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
```

Add this in your app delegate. Where the webview is your app webview.

[STOP UIWebView bounces vertically in device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521001/stop-uiwebview-bounces-vertically-in-device)

Or try this.
Go to Cordova.plist file may be PhoneGap.plist in the supporting files group. Set the topmost key value pair appropriately. Set it it NO for the key UIWebViewBounce.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I edited it have a another try dude. Don't give up :)

Comment: Tried setting up UIWebViewBounce to NO. It partially solves my problem. Now the page does not bounce but the content in the div still bounces. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you thing with doing some calculations of your div.
add:

```
 document.addEventListener("touchStart",<method>,true/false), 

 document.addEventListener("touchMove",<method>,true/false) 

 document.addEventListener("touchEnd",<method>,true/false).
```

When you start scrolling respective methods will start calling. In touchMove specified method calculate the height of the div which you are doing scrolling.

If scrolling came to the end (means div height max reached) allow user to scroll once finger removed `touchEnd` respective method will call. There see the current `e.changedTouches.pageY` it will give you the current place of the div on the scree. simply set the height of the div to the actual height of the div. I hope it will help you

Comment: Sounds promising. Let me try it.